# Sorting a list of objects with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, sorting

I am a novice at coding and whilst I have found examples on Stackoverflow that ought to address my situation, I struggle to understand the syntax and hence convert the example to my needs.

So I have a folder containing Outlook MSG files which I want process in 'Sent date' order. So what I'm trying to do is load them into a list and then sort them by date.

This may be a daft way to do it but I figured that if I create a 'class' containing filename and the date of each message, I could: add these to a list, sort it and then process the list.

So my class looks like this:

```
Class sMSG
    Public sFilename As String
    Public mDate As Date
End Class
```

My code to sort the list (modified from a stackoverflow example), looks like this:

```
            Dim ordered = From obj In SortedList
            OrderBy(obj.mdate Ascending)
            SortedList = ordered.ToList()
```

It generates the error:  BC32017: Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected.

I'm not familiar with this style of coding and can't work out where I am going wrong.

Any help would be appreciated but please be explain it in terms that a complete moron would understand as that just about sums me up at the moment!

Comment: Please give us a link to the example you mention. We may be able to give a better answer with that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        SortedList = (From obj In SortedList Select obj Order By obj.mDate Ascending).ToList()
    'or
    SortedList = SortedList.OrderBy(Function(d) d.mDate)
```

Comment: Many thanks Wojciech, not only does that work but it's also very elegant :-)

Comment: @MaxHeadroom Please accept the answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.